# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I have made a component in react JS which is returning the color name. I just want to store that color name in my parent component , so how can I do this ?

here is my code line which is creating error :

```
{this.setState({navColor: <ChangeNavColor stage={this.state.Stage}/>})}
```

or is there any another way that I can store this component return value in a variable and that variable I will assign to this "navColor" state ?

Comment: Where is this state update being enqueued in relation to the code around it? Where is it in relation to the component it's updating state for? It's also anti-pattern to store JSX in React state, store the data and render the derived UI from it.

Comment: Also, why are you passing a component as a state? You technically can do that, but you are not supposed to. States are for data ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call function :

```
{()=>this.setState({navColor: <ChangeNavColor stage={this.state.Stage}/>})}
```